# f: or p:ajax and JSF with templating doesn't work - Primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, layout, primefaces, templating

I am new here :)
I have got a problem with one of my first web-apps written using JSF.
I wrote a simple template, it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north" header="North - header" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <h:form>
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" header="West - menu" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <h:form>
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center" header="Center - content" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <h:form id="contentForm">
            <ui:insert name="content"/>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="east" header="East - nothing" style="font-size: 15px;">
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" header="South - footer" style="font-size: 15px;">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:head>

<h:body>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And in another file (obrazek.xhtml) I wrote this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
<title>Simple JSF Facelets page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="PHOTOS">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:commandLink action="#{pic.addValue1}">
                    <p:graphicImage url="resources/images/1.png">
                        <p:ajax update="wynik1" event="click"/>
                    </p:graphicImage>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:commandLink action="#{pic.addValue2}">
                    <p:graphicImage url="resources/images/2.png">
                        <p:ajax update="wynik1" event="click"/>
                    </p:graphicImage>
                </h:commandLink>
                <h:outputText value="Obrazek 1: #{pic.val1}" id="wynik1"/>
                <h:outputText value="Obrazek 2: #{pic.val2}" id="wynik2"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>

</html>
```

I wanted to insert some code into "content" primefaces layoutUnit. 
**IDEA:** It has to be 2 pictures and if I click on one of them, AJAX should show the value from ManagedBean using h:outputText. (it always adds +1 to the value :)) 
The problem is: if I dont add templating** into obrazek.xhtml everything works fine, but if I add:

```
<ui:composition template="template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
CODE FROM FORM "PHOTOS" (the one about I called upper that "is no templated"**)
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

while I am clicking on some picture nothing happens. Just "#" is added to my URL and it looks like that:

```
http://localhost:8080/obrazek.xhtml#
```

And my ManagedBean also:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "pic", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class PictureBean {
private int val1;
private int val2;

public void addValue1(){
    val1 += 1;
}

public void addValue2(){
    val2 += 1;
}
GETTERS AND SETTERS FOR VAL1 VAL2
}
```

I have rummaged all the web looking for the answer but uselessly.

Could anyone here help me? :)
Pardon for so long post and not coloured syntax, have to figure out "how to" do it, first :D

Comment: You have nested forms in your xhtml. Try to remove all form-tags from your template-page. Does this already resolve your problem?

Comment: unbelieveable.. it's fine now, big thanks! is it good practice to add forms into template file?
I still don't know when should I add forms in my JSF pages and when not.. :P anyone could tell me that?